# webpack export default works while export object does not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, webpack

I am trying to use implement webpack through an AngularJS.

when I am building and run the application in the production environment, an error is thrown saying that my home controller is unknown. Well it depends how I export my `HomeController` class.

The example below does not work.

```js
// home.controller.js
export class HomeController {
    constructor() {
        this.title = 'Home';
    }
}

// index.js
import { HomeController } from './home.controller.js';

angular.module('home', []).controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

---

The example below works.

```js
// home.controller.js
export default class HomeController {
    constructor() {
        this.title = 'Home';
    }
}

// index.js
import HomeController from './home.controller.js';

angular.module('home', []).controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

---

Here is the rule I am using to transpile JS

```
{
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: /(node_modules|server.js)/,
   use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-classes']
      }
   }]
}
```

Coud it be a bug from webpack or is there something wrong with my rule?

EDIT.

The `export default`does not work either. It only works when I declare the class in the same file as my module.

```
class HomeController {
    constructor() {
        this.title = 'Home';
    }
}

angular.module('home', []).controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

Comment: What do you mean, "does not work"? Error message?

Comment: @AluanHaddad that does not seem to be the issue here glancing at the code the OP posted: uses curlies with the named class export and no curlies on the default export version.

Comment: @JaredSmith you're right, I didn't read it closely enough. It's probably an ESM <-> CJS issue then

Comment: @JaredSmith it was my mistake, I will edit the post. Either the `export default` does not work. The error is just angularJS saying that it cannot find a provider for my class.

Comment: @JaredSmith if you want to see the error: `Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- HomeController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

I forgot the "annotation" "ngInject" in my controller class;

```
class HomeController {
    constructor($timeout) {
        "ngInject"; // <- this is the line I forgot.
        this.title = 'Home';
    }
}
```

When I was using `webpack-dev-server` it would work without the "ngInject" which is pretty weird. It should throw an error anyway.

Also that was my mistake because I didn't precise that I was using a dependency. In my controller.

Thanks for you help.